# Spring REST API, intercept 401 Full authentication required

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've a Spring REST API that offers many endpoints; they require Authentication using Basic http or JWT token. I'm using also a @ControllerAdvice as this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Inject
    private MessageSource messageSource;


    @ExceptionHandler(value = { RuntimeException.class, Exception.class })
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> exceptionHandler(RuntimeException ex, Locale locale) {          
        ErrorMessage error = new ErrorMessage(ApiExceptionCodes.GENERIC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, messageSource.getMessage(
                ApiExceptionCodes.GENERIC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR + "", null, locale));           
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage>(error, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { ApiException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> handlerApiException(ApiException ex, Locale locale) {           
        ErrorMessage error = new ErrorMessage(ex.getCode(), ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage>(error, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { ApiRuntimeException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> handlerApiRuntimeException(ApiRuntimeException ex, Locale locale) {
        ErrorMessage error = new ErrorMessage(ex.getCode(), messageSource.getMessage(ex.getCode() + "", null, locale));
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage>(error, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

One of my endpoints is this:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Return Spring Principal object.", notes = "Return Spring Principal object. It contains several details of the logged-in user.")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('B2B','API')")
public ResponseEntity<?> user(Principal user) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
}
```

In short I'm catching exception globally in my application. Everything works fine aside the exception I've when I try to call a endpoint **without** be authenticated. In that case the exception is not intercepted by my @ControllerAdvice and the user see this body in the response:

```
  <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Error 401 Full authentication is required to access this resource</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>
        <p>Problem accessing /aci/api/v1/tickets/chart. Reason:

            <pre>    Full authentication is required to access this resource</pre>
        </p>
        <hr>
        <a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.9.v20160517</a>
        <hr/>
    </body>
</html>
```

How could I intercept also this exception globally? Please suggest me the best practice to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Basic security you can extend org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint and override commence method to return your custom response, for example:

```
 @Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.addHeader("your_custom_header", "some_value");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.println("HTTP Status 401 - " + authException.getMessage());
}
```